# Knockout JS: Stop divs binded to visible: from flashing on screen

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I am working on a single page applications that has a bunch of hidden divs, binded (or is it bound?) to KnockoutJS with `visible:`. When page loads, they all momentarily flash on screen. I have tried moving my JS into the `<head></head>`, but that had no effect, so loading JS at the bottom of the page is not what's causing it.

Unfortunately, `visible:` binding does not propagate to CSS `display` attribute, so I can not use `display: none;` on page load, or `visible:` will not work at all. Unless... I load the page with `display: none;` and then change it the very first time I show the div to a user.

But is there a more elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to hide the screen while knockout js bindings are being built?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9532595/what-is-the-best-way-to-hide-the-screen-while-knockout-js-bindings-are-being-bui)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Wth KnockoutJS, I work around this problem by defining a CSS class called `hidden` with `display:none`, then I'll add this class and binding to the flashing container:

```
class="hidden" data-bind="css: { hidden: false }"
```

Comment: What they said ^. Thanks for this brilliant answer!

Comment: Nifty indeed. I made one small adjustment to this and replaced "hidden" with "ko-hidden", just for more context and to avoid stepping on an existing "hidden" class: `class="ko-hidden" data-bind="css: { 'ko-hidden': false }"`

Comment: It is worth noting bootstrap 3 has a `.hidden` class. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-show-hide

Comment: I thought of doing this, but couldn't grasp why the `visible` binding didn't seem to do exactly this. As the question says, the `visible` binding doesn't seem to take precedent over the stylesheet rules, which is rather baffling. At least this works.

Comment: @crush Because the binding doesn't take effect until you call applyBindings.

Comment: @Tuan That's not what I'm talking about at all. In the case where you have applied a `display: none` via a CSS class, the `visible` binding won't work when the observable to which it is bound is true. When the `visible` binding's bound value evaluates to true, it simply sets `element.style.display = ''` which effectively removes `style="display: none"` from the element. Then, the underlying CSS class, which has `display: none` is applied - thus the element never shows. Therefore, the only work-arounds are to use `style="display: none"`, instead of classes, or a special presentational class.

Comment: The only way that the `visible` binding could be made to work with css classes in the instance where you want the class to start as `display: none`, would be to have an optional binding argument that specifies what `display` style to use when the `visible` binding evaluates to true since it wouldn't be specified in the css class (it's specified as `none` there). Something like `visible: isVisible(), visibleDisplayType: 'block'`. Of course, this doesn't exist, so it would need to be added.

Answer (score 5):

I solved this by putting my "flashy" content in a script template and use ko's virtual elements to load the template when the variable is set by another virtual element.

For example:

```
<!-- ko if: myVariable -->
<!-- ko template: { name: 'myTemplate' } --><!-- /ko -->
<script type="text/html" id="myTemplate">
    <ul data-bind="foreach: blah...">
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</script>
<!-- /ko -->
```

So when myVariable is set, the content of the script container will be put in place of the template virtual element. With this method you dont see any flashing content :-)

Comment: this has the bonus of not putting display:none on everything (when someone else removes data-bind they may not remember to remove display:none

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing a custom binding to use instead of the default `visible`.

```
function isHidden(el) {
    var style;

    style = window.getComputedStyle(el);

    return (style.display === 'none')
}

ko.bindingHandlers['cssVisible'] = {
    'update': function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value,
            isCurrentlyVisible;

        value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        isCurrentlyVisible = !isHidden(element);

        if (value && !isCurrentlyVisible) {
            ko.utils.toggleDomNodeCssClass(element, 'ko-visible', true);
        }
        else if ((!value) && isCurrentlyVisible) {
            ko.utils.toggleDomNodeCssClass(element, 'ko-visible', false);
        }
    }
}
```

Then some CSS to handle visibility

```
[data-bind*="cssVisible"]:not(.ko-visible) {
    display: none;
}
```

Usage is the same as the `visible` binding

```
<div data-bind="cssVisible: true"></div>
```